# sumArray JavaScript

Tags: javascript

La función llamada `sumArray` recibe como argumento un arreglo de números ordenados llamado *array* y un número.

```js
// entero llamdo 'n' y debe devolver true si alguna combinación de dos números cualesquiera del arreglo sumados
// dan n, y devuelva false si ninguna combinación de dos números sumados da como resultado el número n.

// Ej:
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)  debería devolver false ya que no es posible sumar 14 con dos números del arreglo
// Pista: Podes usar bucles/ciclos anidados
// Aclaración: No es válido sumar el mismo número dos veces
// Ej:
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 4)  Si bien 2 + 2 = 4 no está permitido sumar el mismo número dos veces
// por lo tanto también debería devolver false en este caso
```

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: directamente nada estoy en blanco

Comment: @user215203 te recomiendo mucho leas [ask]

Answer (score 2):

### Solución

Una posible solución pasaría por:

```js
const sumArray = (array, numero) => {
  const size = array.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const a = array[i];

    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (i === j) continue;
      const b = array[j];
      if (a + b === numero) return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

console.log(sumArray([2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 15, 20], 13));
```

### Explicación

Obviamente, se *necesitarán dos bucles* para tomar un elemento del *array* y luego sumarlo con cualquier otro para luego compararlo con el segundo argumento, que es el número.

Empecemos por:

```js
const size = array.length;
```

En ella obtenemos la longitud (tamaño) del *array* para iterar los bucles.

Luego, tenemos nuestro bucle principal:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const a = array[i];
    ...
}
```

Que es el que tomará un número cualquiera del *array* (empezando por el primero) para sumarlo con uno de los otros números.

Es decir:

```js
const a = array[i];
```

Dentro de nuestro *bucle principal* está el otro bucle que se encuentra anidado en él y es la que sumará un número cualquiera (`a = array[i]`) tomado del bucle padre con cualquier otro (`b = array[j]`) tomado de él dentro del mismo *array*.

Por ejemplo:

```js
for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
  // Esto evita que sume el mismo número dos veces:
  if (i === j) continue;

  // El otro número tomado por el bucle anidado
  // en el bucle principal:
  const b = array[j];

  // Se suman los números a y b y se comparan
  // con «numero»:
  if (a + b === numero) return true;
}
```

### Con algo de validaciones

Pero, podemos hacerla un poco más *difícil* agregando algunas validaciones:

1. Verificar si el primer argumento es un *array*.
2. Si los elementos del *array* son numéricos.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const sumArray = (array, numero) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) return false;

  const size = array.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const a = array[i];

    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (i === j || isNaN(a)) continue;

      const b = array[j];
      if (a + b === numero) return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

console.log( sumArray([2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 15, 20], 13 ) )
```

Donde la línea:

```js
if (!Array.isArray(array)) return false;
```

Hará que nuestra función devuelva `false` si el primer argumento no es un *array* y la siguiente línea:

```js
if (i === j || isNaN(a)) continue;
```

Hará que nuestro *bucle* que se encuentra anidado en el *bucle principal* continúe sin ejecutar las demás líneas que se encuentren en él si el elemento a evaluar (`isNaN(a)`) no es un *número*. Esto es, sin tomar en cuenta que si `i === j` también continuará para evitar sumar dos veces el mismo número.

Nuestra función podrá devolver `false` si todos los elementos del *array* no es numérico, ya que es su valor por defecto.